# Display real time data from external website in Swing interface?

Tags: java, swing, real-time

I've tried googling the web but every question seems to address web development. I'm simply wondering if it is even possible to fetch data from internet (game results and in game events) that is updated every second ,or every 10 second and so on ,from a website that's not mine and to display it in a Java desktop client with the Swing library interface? And if yes, what is the best method?

ThankYou

Comment: I'm merely asking if it's possible before I waste my time trying something that won't work. I'm asking, because like I wrote, all I get when I search around is a bunch of web development related results.

Comment: It's possible, you can start

Comment: If you are making lots of request to a Website, that is not yours, you should consider asking the Website owner, if you may do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get stock data when requested, rather than on a timer, but you can look at my code and see how I get the stock data.

Here's what the JPanel looks like.  It's the panel on the right.

[image: Stock Picker JPanel]

This is the HistoricalDataRunnable class.

```
package com.ggl.stock.picker.controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.ggl.stock.picker.model.Company;
import com.ggl.stock.picker.model.StockDay;
import com.ggl.stock.picker.model.StockHistory;
import com.ggl.stock.picker.model.StockPickerModel;
import com.ggl.stock.picker.view.StockPickerFrame;

public class HistoricalDataRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static final String URLString = 
                  "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?output=csv&q=";

    private Company company;

    private StockPickerFrame frame;

    private StockPickerModel model;

    public HistoricalDataRunnable(StockPickerFrame frame,
            StockPickerModel model, Company company) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
        this.company = company;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            String symbol = company.getStockSymbol();

            URL url = new URL(URLString + symbol);
            URLConnection hc = url.openConnection();
            hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; "
                    + "Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) "
                    + "Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
            is = hc.getInputStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            processCSVFile(br);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String message = e.getMessage();
            message = "<html>" + message;
            setMessageLabel(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String message = e.getMessage();
            message = "<html>" + message;
            setMessageLabel(message);
        } finally {
            closeReaders(is, br);
        }
    }

    private void processCSVFile(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String line = "";
        int count = 0;
        StockHistory history = new StockHistory(company);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (count > 0) {
                StockDay stockDay = createStockDay(line);
                if (stockDay != null) {
                    history.addStockDay(stockDay);
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (history.calculateNumbers()) {
            model.addStockHistory(history);
            addStockHistory();
            setMessageLabel(" ");
        } else {
            String message = "<html>There is no data for "
                    + company.getCompanyName();
            setMessageLabel(message);
        }
    }

    private StockDay createStockDay(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        if (parts[1].equals("-"))
            return null;

        double open = Double.valueOf(parts[1]);
        double high = Double.valueOf(parts[2]);
        double low = Double.valueOf(parts[3]);
        double close = Double.valueOf(parts[4]);
        long volume = Long.valueOf(parts[5]);
        return new StockDay(parts[0], open, high, low, close, volume);
    }

    private void addStockHistory() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.addStockHistory();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setMessageLabel(final String text) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setMessageLabel(text);
                ;
            }
        });
    }

    private void closeReaders(InputStream is, BufferedReader br) {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This class makes a URL connection with Google, and returns the historical stock information. This information is captured in a StockHistory instance, and stored in the StockPickerModel instance.

The User-Agent property is set to simulate a browser. Some web sites don’t allow programs to access their web server. By setting the User-Agent property, you can pretend to be a web browser. Your program should respect the web server, and not submit too many requests. How much is too many depends on the web server.

This class also updates the view. The only way we’ll know when the request is complete is when the HistoricalDataRunnable method receives a response from Google. It’s up to this class to update the model and the view.

Since this class is run in a separate thread, we have to call the SwingUtilities invokeLater method to execute any Swing GUI commands. That’s why the addStockHistory and setMessageLabel methods are enclosed in an invokeLater method.

This class displays any errors in the JLabel message. The stock might not be kept by Google. The stock may not have any stock day values. These error messages are displayed.

To see the rest of the code, take a look at my [Stock Picker Using Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=709) article.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it. You should use java.net package to work with network.

Data fetching depends on the site from which you are going to fetch data, for example:

- If site have API, like [Stack Overflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), you should use it.
- If data is presented on the page, you can use parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (if page is html, of course)